# Post hidden input array with quotes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This form has questions and answers. I have radio buttons for any questions with only one correct answer. Corrently I am using jQuery to gather all the radio button values and assign them to the hidden field when submitted. (If I don't use jQuery, it will assign the same 'name' to all the radio button elements making them all in the same group)

The problem I am having is when I am assigning the radio button values to the hidden field they are posting like this:

```
"answer_ids"=>["49,60,62,9,14,18,64,", "2"],
```

The last "2" is from questions with checkboxes where I am able to keep the values as these inputs can have the same name since I don't care how many are checked.

The first group of numbers are the values I need in the right format. I tried split(',') and it works but the actual value doesn't seem to change to an array as the var answers has.

I need:

```
"answer_ids"=>["49", "60", "62", "9", "14", "18", "64", "2"],
```

How do you get the quotes in the right place?

```
<%= form_for(@score) do |f| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :test_id, @test.id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "answer_ids[]", [] %>
<% @i = 0 %>
<% @a = ("a".."z").to_a %>
<legend><%= @test.name %></legend>
<% @test.question_ids.each do |q| %>
<% @question = Question.find(q) %>
<% @i += 1 %>
<% @answers = @question.answers %>
<% if (@answers.where(correct: true).count == 1) %>
      <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="radios"><b><%= @i %>.&nbsp;</b><%= @question.content %></label>
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <% @answers.each_with_index do |me, i| %>
          <div class="radio">
            <span style="margin-left: 35px;">
                <%= radio_button_tag @question.id, me.id %> <!-- "answer_ids[]" -->
                <%= @a[i] %>.
                &nbsp;
                <%= me.option %>
            </span>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% else %>
      <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="checkboxes"><b><%= @i %>.&nbsp;</b><%= @question.content %></label>
      <div class="col-md-11">
        Select all that apply:<br/>
        <% @answers.each_with_index do |me, i| %>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <span style="margin-left: 35px;">
                <%= check_box_tag 'answer_ids[]', me.id %>
                <%= @a[i] %>.
                &nbsp;
                <%= me.option %>
            </span>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Save Test", id: "commit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary save" %>
</div>
<% end %>
<script>
$('.new_score').on('submit', function() {
    var input = "";
    $( "form input:radio:checked" ).each(function(i, obj) {
        input += (obj.value) + ","
    });
    var answers = input.split(',');
    $('input[type=hidden][name="answer_ids[]"]').val(answers)
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would it be easier to us jQuery to append a new hidden field per value instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to append the input once submitted so ruby on rails doens't know anything different. This simply adds a checkbox hidden input that is checked to the form with the value for each radio selected.

```
$( "form input:radio:checked" ).each(function(i, obj) {
         $('#new_score').append('<input id="answer_ids_'+i+'" name="answer_ids[]" type="hidden" value="'+obj.value+'" checked>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible for you to provide the html code that is generated at your browser so that I can understand the structure properly. I know jQuery but I dont know your scenario and the template engine you are using

Comment: Why is this an answer, this should be a comment

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to comment. It asked me to have a reputation of at least 50 :)

Comment: Oh okay I see, There is enough code. The answer lies in the script.